# Change font-family after font-awesome icon

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-family, font-awesome-5

I am builting a website using font-awesome icons and I noticed that the font-family changes when I use an icon.

I've read online about pseudo elements, but yet can't figure it out.

Is there any way (example of code), that I can use so as to inherit the same font-family which is used in the webiste, after using a font awesome icon?

Many thanks!

[image]

```html
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/cce2885033.js"></script>

<br><i class="fa fa-check"> If the athlete does not have time and has to eat 1 hour before the game, 70g are usually enough.</i><br>
```

Comment: Do not add text inside `fa-` classed nodes. It's not best practice. Keep it separate.

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I did add a snippet. Would you think that there may be a way to have a control over the font-family after the check icon?

Comment: as @Prajwal said, this is not how font should be used,read the DOC. Don't put text inside `i`

Comment: Oh I see guys. Make sense know! many thanks for your effort and I appreciate your time helping me resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Font-Awesome applies its own font family. Use it like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-check"></i><p style="font-family:'yourfont';">TEXT</p>
```

OR use pseudo element ::before in css to apply font-awesome icon to the left(before) of your text without icon tag:

```
p::before {
 font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 3px;
 font-weight: 900;
 content: "\f00c";
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I have already tried @Prajwals' recomendation and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might do it setting several font names to `font-family` property:

```css
i.fa {font-family: "FontAwesome", "Lobster", sans-serif}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/cce2885033.js"></script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet"> 
 
<br><i class="fa fa-check"> If the athlete does not have time and has to eat 1 hour before the game, 70g are usually enough.</i><br>
```